# How to simplify python logging code

Tags: python, logging, wrapper

I want to log a start/end of my any function - how can I simplify this code as wrapper or something else?

```
@task()
def srv_dev(destination=development):
    logging.info("Start task " + str(inspect.stack()[0][3]).upper())
    configure(file_server, destination)
    logging.info("End task " + str(inspect.stack()[0][3]).upper())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [decorator](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) (what you already do via `@task()`). Here is a decorator that logs the name of any function at the beginning and end in capital letters:

```
import logging
import inspect
import functools

def log_begin_end(func):
    """This is a decorator that logs the name of `func` (in capital letters).

    The name is logged at the beginning and end of the function execution.

    """
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):

        logging.info("Start task " + func.__name__.upper())
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        logging.info("End task " + func.__name__.upper())
        return result

    return new_func
```

Usage like the following:

```
@log_begin_end
def myfunc(x,y,z):
    pass  # or do whatever you want
```

Of course, you can cascade decorators. Thus, in your case you might use:

```
@task()
@log_begin_end
def srv_dev(destination=development):
    configure(file_server, destination)
```

Now calling `srv_dev()` will log:

> Start task SRV_DEV
>
> End task SRV_DEV